# Flyway migration failing on index creation

Tags: spring, h2, flyway

I have the following SQL script that is failing during flyway migration:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS idx_name ON inserttablename(customer_id);
```

An SQL syntax error is thrown, giving the below output:

```
13:23:47  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load 
ApplicationContext
13:23:47  Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
13:23:47  Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in 
class path resource[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfigurati on$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
13:23:47  Migration V5__242141241.sql failed
13:23:47  --------------------------------------
13:23:47  SQL State  : 42001
13:23:47  Error Code : 42001
13:23:47  Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE INDEX 
CONCURRENTLY IF[*] NOT EXISTS IDX_NAME ON INSERTTABLENAME(CUSTOMER_ID)"; 
expected "., ON"; SQL statement:
13:23:47  CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS 
idx_name ON tablename(customer_id) [42001-200]
13:23:47  Location   : db/migration/V5__242141241.sql 
13:23:47  Line       : 1
13:23:47  Statement  : CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS 
idx_name ON inserttablename(customer_id)
13:23:47  
13:23:47  Caused by: 
org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
13:23:47  
13:23:47  Migration V5__242141241.sql failed
13:23:47  SQL State  : 42001
13:23:47  Error Code : 42001
13:23:47  Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE INDEX 
CONCURRENTLY IF[*] NOT 
EXISTS IDX_NAME ON INSERTTABLENAME(CUSTOMER_ID)"; expected "., ON"; SQL 
statement:
13:23:47  CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS idx_name ON 
inserttablename(customer_id) [42001-200]
```

Executing the same query in pgadmin's query tool works fine with the index being created. Also the same type of migration, with the same SQL query undergoing flyway migration for a different table, was successful previously - even while using the same versions of flyway and h2 in the two different services.

Any inputs would be appreciated

Comment: pgadmin isn't connected to H2. If you it the same query that is working on H2 (as you state) it should work, apparently it isn't and there is a typo somewhere. Do a careful comparison of both queries.

Comment: I know they're not connected. I was pointing out that the query to create the index worked in pgadmin but not through flyway although the query is identical.
If there was a typo it would have been caught in pgadmin's console

Comment: You mention H2 in your question so I don't see how that is related then? But as stated **if** the queries are the same they would execute. But apparently they aren't. Also the error you get also looks like an H2 error and not a Postgres error. Hence it appears as if you are trying to execute PostgreSQL queries on H2. Could you add additional logging to your question? The things that happen before this, I also wonder are you using Spring Boot or plain Spring?

Comment: I am using spring-boot and I'm using h2 to execute postgresql queries. I will update the question with additional logging,

Comment: Doesn't look like concurrently is an option in h2 create index command https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_index

Comment: @johnnyutts yeah that seems strange - as this option previously worked. Unless h2 have since stopped supporting this

Comment: You cannot execute PostgreSQL queries on H2 as that isn't PostgreSQL (and no running it in compatibility mode doesn't count as it only supports a small number of additional PostgreSQL query things).

Comment: looks like the integration tests were using h2 in-mem which was causing the issue. Disabled flyway in the tests and migration worked fine on app startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the integration tests were using h2 in-mem which was causing the pipeline issue. Disabled flyway in the tests and migration worked fine on app startup